# Copylefted introduction to topology

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, textbook-recommendation

Is there a textbook in topology with a copyleft license?

$$ $$

Comment: I have an unfinished book that I intended to copyleft when finished, but I have not found time to work on it for a while.  I could send you that if you like.  What do you want to do with such a book, exactly?

Comment: @NeilStrickland sure yes, see my email.

Comment: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/

Comment: @CarloBeenakker it is not an intro to topology, also it is free but not copyleft.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin [This](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Top/Topdownloads.html) is probably what Carlo Beenakker was referring to. It is still probably not under copyleft, but it is an intro to (point-set) topology.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: maybe you can edit with what you mean by intro to topology? Not just how little, but also how much. For example, the first three chapters of Hatcher's Intro Notes can also be found in many textbooks introducing analysis; presumably you want more than just that. (I note also that you tagged at.algebraic-topology on the question.)

Comment: @AntonPetrunin -- this is a bit confusing for me: Hatcher's text book I linked to is not actually licensed, but it is free to download and distribute; how would the use you have in mind be restriced by this permission? I understood "copyleft" as mainly relevant for software.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: if you are referring to Hatcher's _Algebraic Topology_, it is [not copyleft](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATcopyright.html). The only textbook that I am aware of with an explicit copyleft license is Fremlin's [_Measure Theory_](https://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm). But I usually don't keep track of the distinction between freely available and copyleft. (The distinction is basically that the latter allows modifications provided that the modifications are also published copyleft.)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Assume you want to modify the book a bit.

Comment: @WillieWong I would be interested in any copylefted text, but since you ask I need an introduction to point-set topology, plus a bit of algebraic topology.

Comment: There isn't one, not in English. But it sounds like an interesting project for someone to seed.